# Add std value to line plot (using yerr parameter) raise an error: AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'yerr'

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot

I have data frame which has data about mean value of different group and their std, similar to this:

```
index   timestamp    mean1   std1   mean2  std2  mean3   std3
0       2022/11/01   0.542   0.07   0.729  0.21   0.375   0.08
1       2022/11/02   0.623   0.05   0.811  0.04   0.211   0.11
...
```

I want to plot the three means per day and to display the std. For that I have seen that I can use the [plot function of matplotlib, and to add the variable  "yerr"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html) and to put the name of the std columns. However, I keetp getting this error:

> 'Line2D' object has no property 'yerr'

I have used this script:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D 

ax=plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,1],color='tab:blue',yerr='std1',linestyle='-',linewidth=1.8)
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,3],color='black',yerr='std2',linestyle='-',linewidth=1.8)
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,5],color='tab:red',,yerr='std3',linestyle='-',linewidth=1.8)
plt.xticks(fontsize=16, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
```

how can I fix it and display the error on top of the lines?
the script works when I don't add the yerr parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 'plt.plot()' to try and include the error bars, yet the linked function is 'plt.errorbar()'. I think that 'plt.plot()' [does not have the optional argument 'yerr'](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) and that's the reason for the error. I suggest substituting your 'plt.plot()' by 'plt.errorbar()' and it should work:)